# Preventing QGIS from Loading Online Service Capabilities at Project Startup?

Tags: qgis, wms, getcapabilities

I'm working with a QGIS project that includes multiple online services (WMS, WFS, etc.), and I've encountered significant delays when starting the project. QGIS attempts to load the capabilities of these services even if they are not active or visible, which not only slows down the project startup time but can also be problematic with a slow or absent Internet connection.

Is there a way to prevent QGIS from automatically retrieving the capabilities of online services at startup?

I'm looking for a solution that could either delay this process until the layers are actually needed or disable the automatic loading altogether without having to manually deactivate each service before closing the project.

I'm currently using QGIS 3.34.

[image]

Comment: Hi, why do you think the delay is due web registered services? I think that they are not loaded when the project opens, but when a layer from some of those services is turned on. For example, if you don't unregister any service but close the Navigator panel in your QGIS profile, there are delays too?

Comment: All of the services are turned off, but the project load debugger indicates that the capabilities are requested. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: great, thank you. Just to verify, it also happens if you close the Browser panel?

Comment: same with closed Browser panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need all of these Layers everytime, you could make a simple Plugin with pyqgis, with which you can toggle the layers in and out of your project. So the layers wont be loaded if you do not need them.